# Manually create order Magento2

Tags: orders, magento2.2.2

I had to restore from back up meaning that some orders after the backup was taken have been lost. I have the order details but want to restore them so the customer can see them.

How do I manually create orders ?

Comment: What if those orders were paid by credit card or paypal what would you do then?

Comment: Just add a comment to say they paid and the paypal transaction id. The problem is if the customer logs in then there order is missing so it's a poor experience for them.